# How to clear retrieve log in plugin registration tool

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, registration, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm using plugin registration tool.

In the section:  Debug -> setup tab -> Retrieve log -> 'select profile from CRM' popup, I need to clear all logs from **'select profile from CRM'** popup.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be stored in CRM entity - `Plugin Profiles`. Delete the unwanted old records.

You can do Advanced Find for that entity or navigate to Settings - Extensions.

[image]

[image]